# Let a user change background of identity login by a button? - Blazor

Tags: blazor

I'm building Blazor + identity, with WebApi.

When a user is signed, he/she can upload an image and set that image as the background for identity/login.cshtml by clicking a button.

Is that possible? I've been google around for a few days and couldn't find anything useful.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question completely. Why do you want to show the user's image on the login page? The only time they will see that page is when they aren't (yet) logged in, so how do you know which user's image to show?

Also, I suspect your question isn't specific to Blazor. If you want to know how to upload a file in Blazor, there are plenty of resources for that, including [Microsoft's own docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0). If you want to know how to display an image once uploaded to the server, you just use the HTML `<img>` tag.

Maybe if you could clarify your question a bit, we'd be able to give you a better answer.